# OneNote displays wrong name for contributor

Tags: gmail, microsoft-onenote

I shared my own OneNote notebook with another account of mine, lets say bruce.wayne@gmail.com. It uses my actual name both for the email adress and the display name "Bruce Wayne". I created the account a long time ago, when I was still a young teen. OneNote displays the account name with the correct email, but as "Sun Tzu" (example). The name is not familiar to me, but it is close enough to aliases I used online when I created the gmail account. I would not rule out having messed with the account settings more than a decade ago and at one point entering an alias like "Sun Tzu" instead of "Bruce Wayne". I have connected the correct account, there's no typo. If it is in fact an old alias, how does OneNote get that historic info and why does it display it instead my actual name? In emails my actual name shows up correctly, I also checked the Google account, but that alias is nowhere to be found. Or does OneNote use random placeholder names for some reason?

What could be behind the alias as the contributor name instead of my actual name?

Comment: Does your computer date from 10 years ago?

Comment: No, it is fairly new (~2yrs). Also, I've never actually used OneNote with any account or linked any Windows application to the the Bruce Wayne account. The main account (that's used for oneNote) is very new, I created it when I installed Win10 last year.